# Is Ruby 2 backward compatible with Ruby 1?

Tags: ruby

I have a project in Ruby 2. Can I run my project in Ruby 1?

Comment: You need to give more details about versions - at least minor version numeber (1.X, 2.X), optimally - patch number (1.X.Y, 2.X.Y).

Comment: Probably not. Why would you do that?

Comment: It depends on whether you use any Ruby 2 features, and if so, which. New methods might be retrofitted via the [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem, although not all (e.g. `Module.prepend`). Converting new literals / syntax features is probably harder. Encoding could become an issue. It really depends on your code and Ruby versions.

Comment: But don't get me wrong: I'm just saying that it _might_ be doable, not that it should be done. You should rather spend your time on upgrading that other system to Ruby 2. Move forward, not backwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Many features have been introduced in Ruby 2 since Ruby 1. That would make your Ruby 2 code fail when run on Ruby 1.

By the way, backward compatible is like when code written in Ruby 1 can run on Ruby 2. You are asking the opposite: whether code written in Ruby 2 can run on Ruby 1. That is not backward compatibility.

Comment: Not to mention that ruby 1 and ruby 2 is not really sufficient either since there are definitely backwards compatibility issues between minor versions `1.8.7` => `1.9.3` and `2.0.0` through `2.5.x`

Comment: Thanks, So if I have written the code in Ruby 1, can I run the same code in Ruby 2?

Comment: Code written in Ruby 1.8 had errors when run on Ruby 1.9. It may, or may not raise an error in Ruby 2. It depends on your code.